# The Discrete Logarithm problem

Tags: cryptography, algorithms

I am puzzled with the following discrete logarithm problem:

Given positive integers `b, c, m` where `(b < m) is True` it is to find a positive integer `e` such that

```
(b**e % m == c) is True
```

where two stars is exponentiation (e.g. in Ruby, Python or ^ in some other languages) and % is modulo operation. Using general math symbols it looks like:($b^e \equiv c (\mod m)$).

What is the most effective algorithm (with the lowest big-O complexity) to solve it ?

Example:
Given b=5; c=8; m=13 this algorithm must find e=7 because 5**7%13 = 8

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Google is your friend.  Search for "discrete logarithm", which is what this problem is usually called.

Comment: Talking complexity theory, algorithms and the like, in programming language...you're more likely to get a good response over at Stack Overflow than here, I think.

Comment: Do you want to deal with m a prime, or general m? If m is a prime, the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm is quite detailed. Note that many of the algorithms there are only worth implementing for m in the 10's of digits. 

Comment: @Charles: users of stackoverflow have directed me to the mathoverflow :)

Comment: @David: there is no explanation in terms of complexity on the wikipedia

Comment: Really? I scanned the wikipedia articles on the 7 algorithms listed there, and most of them had complexity bounds.

Comment: @psihodella: The trouble with this question is that it's not asking for anything that's not ***widely*** documented in the literature. Of course, *the* most effective algorithm may not be known to anyone, but the known algorithms are easy to find details on. The Wikipedia article refers to several algorithms and, if you follow the links, you'll find information on their running time.

Comment: -1 for too localized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is not phrased to our taste at mathoverflow, but the user has a point that this particular Wikipedia page is under-developed.  As David Speyer suggests, it is a very different problem for very large primes than for small ones.  For small primes the simplest algorithms described in Wikipedia are probably the most appropriate.  If the question is instead about the theoretical time complexity, see [this review article](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~psh/ANTproc/12oliver.pdf).